# How to make the top command calculate the CPU usage per second?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, top

I am using `top` in Solaris mode via `top -d 1` and it shows that one of my processes is using around 45% of CPU.

Question:

- Since I'm using `-d 1` does that mean that process is using around half of my cores per second?
- If not then how am I able to calculate the CPU usage per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `45%` usage you're seeing for your application is most likely the usage on one core of the CPU, which is why you can have the sum of the numbers in the `%CPU` column exceed `100%`.

If you want to know the total CPU usage on your system every second, you can use the `id` attribute (IDLE) of the `top` output. Once that is divided by the number of cores (`nproc --all`), you will get the current CPU usage:

```bash
top -bn2 | grep '%Cpu' | tail -1 | grep -P '(....|...) id,' | awk -v cores=$(nproc --all) '{print "CPU Usage: " ($8/cores) "%"}'
```

Some alternative methods to get the total CPU usage methods:

##### vmstat

```bash
echo "CPU Usage: "$[100-$(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $15}')]"%"
```

This command will parse through the results of [`vmstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vmstat) with a second of delay, then subtract the free CPU space from `100` and give you the amount that is currently in use.

##### /proc/stat

```bash
cat /proc/stat | grep cpu | tail -1 | awk '{print "CPU Usage: " ($5*100)/($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10) "%"}'
```

To parse out the information of interest, we use the following calculation:

```
Average idle time (%) = (idle * 100) / (user + nice + system + idle + iowait + irq + softirq + steal + guest + guest_nice)
```

---

References:

- https://www.tutorialworks.com/linux-top-command-explained/
- https://www.baeldung.com/linux/get-cpu-usage

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, as you can see I've mentioned that I'm using `top` in the Solaris mode therefore, my CPU usage does not exceed 100% and is showing the CPU usage of all available cores. My question is focused on the `per second` matter, does your answer give me the amount of CPU usage per second? If yes then what part exactly focuses on the `per second`? From `top` manual the CPU usage is calculated between each screen update and since I'm using `-d 1` to force screen updates with one second interval I want to know if that achieves it